# Moving wordpress site from live server to localhost

Tags: wordpress

Downloaded the files from live server and installed in my local system and imported database in my localhost and updated the urls in database as well.Updated the url by using this code.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://oldurl/','http://newurl/') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://oldurl/','http://newurl/');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content,'http://oldurl/','http://newurl/');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://oldurl/','http://newurl/');
```

But the issue is only i am to check the home page if i click on any link in menu or any other it is redirecting to xampp server.If i try to open admin panel as well it is redirecting to xampp dashboard

Comment: may I know how your new URL is looking like?

Comment: Can anyone please help me this

Comment: @ManvendraRajpurohit my newurl looks like this http://localhost:8080/carrollton

Comment: So that code you've given us did you update the values in there? or copied it like that exactly?

Comment: change permalink to default once and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use database URL replace tool, search and db replace from below URL,

[Search and DB Replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Download it and put it in localhost folder and run from broswer, follow steps like,

Provide wordpress db name, live url (in from text box: search for…), local url (replace by textbox: replace with…) and your local host username and password.

First check db connection after provide all details by click on dry run, once it do do live run.

It will replace all live URL to local url into your local wordpress database.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you use the Duplicator plugin to install a copy of a WordPress site onto your localhost server.  It handles all the URL changes for your automatically.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Answer (score 0):

```
         use database URL replace tool, search and db replace from below URL,   [Serch and Replace]


       [1]: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
        Then Download Your Project and paste in localhost then change the file in WP-config.php.in it change  user name, password, host.an then run project.
```